# npm start Error 2

Tags: npm, angular

While running 'npm start', I am getting the following errors:

```
app/app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
    app/main.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.

npm ERR! weird error 2

npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"

npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
```

The error occurs while running the typescript file and not during the javascript file. I have even tried the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy


sudo npm update -g && sudo npm install -g concurrently lite-server typescript
```

But still the error persists. What to do?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS. node version:6.2.0, nodejs:0.10.25 and working on Angular2.

Comment: Could you provide the content of your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` files? Thanks!

Comment: Did you do `npm install` (not `-g` or anything) in your project's directory?

Comment: @CherryDT Yes. It did not worked. Then I tried `sudo npm install` and it worked for me. But still why it worked, I don't  know.

Comment: Then please add your solution as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using: `npm install`.
 Use: `sudo npm install` in the same directory, that worked for me.

You can also do: `sudo npm install -g` to install it globally.
But yes, remember to have the latest nodejs installed in your system. 
Hope that helps.

Don't forget to use the angular2 library.

To eliminate, the following error:
`app/app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
 app/main.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.`

Do:
`npm install angular2 --save`

and replace the import with:

`import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
 import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';`

Hope it helps.If not surely do comment.

Comment: Angular2 package declaration has changed from 'angular2' to '@angular' in RC1